# Cakephp how to get 1st and last datetime of a month

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to get 1st and last datetime by [FrozenTime](https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.I18n.FrozenTime.html#startOfMonth())

I have written below function

```
public function getFristAndLastDate($year,$month)
{
        $time = FrozenTime::now()->setDate((int)$year, (int)$month, 01)->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

        return [
            $time->startOfMonth(),
            $time->endOfMonth()
        ];
}
```

After call function I am getting error

> Call to a member function startOfMonth() on string

How can I get 1st and last datetime from year and month in cakephp using FrozenTime ?

Comment: You are formatting your object into a string... so... don't do that!

Comment: @ndm is correct. That first line of the function sets time to a string. Read here: read https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.I18n.FrozenTime.html#i18nFormat() so just remove that part and set the format elsewhere like $time->startOfMonth()->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **create function** to create a new ChronosInterface instance from a specific date and time.

```
FrozenTime::create((int) $year, (int) $month);
```